# google chart modify hAxis date format in range filter listener

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I want to change hAxis date format in range filter.
for example if i have set format like 'dd-MMM-yyyy'

```js
var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            chartType: 'ComboChart',
            dataTable: view,
            options: {
                
                hAxis: { format: 'dd-MM-yyyy'},
                
                },
                areaOpacity: 1.0
            },
            containerId: 'chart_div'
        });
```

now i want that in listener if range is more than one year then change format of chart like format: 'MM-yyyy' etc.
using bellow listener.

```html
google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', function (e) {

            if (!e.inProgress) {
            var difference_days = (control.getState().range.end - control.getState().range.start) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

    if (difference_days >= 180){
        //if more than six months then remove days from format
        //hAxis: { format: 'MM-yyyy'},
    }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the `setOption` method on the chart wrapper

```
chart.setOption('hAxis.format', 'MM-yyyy');
chart.draw();
```

anytime you change an option, the chart must be redrawn...